# Mass Assignment error in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, mass-assignment

i'm having issues with my nested form when submiting it.

My two models:

```
#PLANNING MODEL
class Planning < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :periods
   belongs_to :plannable, polymorphic: true
   attr_accessible :quantity, :periods_attributes
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :periods
end

#PERIOD MODEL
class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :planning
   attr_accessible :planned_quantity, :planning_id
end
```

and in my form:

```
 ...
 <% @planning.periods.each do |period| %>
   <%= f.fields_for(period) do |builder| %>
     <%= builder.label :planned_quantity, "Planned quantity" %>
     <%= builder.number_field :planned_quantity%>
   <%end%>
 <%end%>
 ...
```

Everything is showing just like I wanted until I submit, when it shows the following:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: period
```

Does anyone knows how to help me? Been searching the whole web...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding `:period` to the `attr_accessible` whitelist in the planning model?

Comment: @rjz yes, already tried that and it returns the error `unknown attribute: period`

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the @planning.periods.each, just do this

```
<%= f.fields_for :periods do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.label :planned_quantity, "Planned quantity" %>
  <%= builder.number_field :planned_quantity%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: tried it and now it shows no record in my form, as if i didn't have any period created (i'm `3.times { @planning.periods.build }` in the `plannings_controller/new`

Answer (score 0):

define your attribute in `attr_accessible` as this :

```
attr_accessible :planned_quantity, :planning_id, :period
```

Comment: no, i recieve the message `unknown attribute: period`. why would i want a :planning_id attribute in the planning model?!